# Expanding dataframe based on the date difference in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, numpy

I have a scenario as below

scenario1:

```
FromDate    ToDate
15-01-2018  15-12-2018
15-12-2018  15-10-2020
...
15-10-2020  15-11-2020
15-11-2020  15-12-2020
15-12-2020  15-01-2021
```

Here there is no continuation from **15-01-2018** to **15-12-2018** and also **15-12-2018** to **15-10-2020** so I would like to get the above dataframe as below.

```
FromDate    ToDate
15-01-2018  15-02-2018
15-02-2018  15-03-2018
15-03-2018  15-04-2018
...
15-11-2018  15-12-2018
15-12-2018  15-01-2020
15-01-2020  15-02-2020
15-02-2020  15-03-2020
...
15-09-2020  15-10-2020
15-10-2020  15-11-2020
15-11-2020  15-12-2020
15-12-2020  15-01-2021
```

Is there a way where I can achieve this?

scenario2:
in the scenario2 last FromDate is **15-12-2020** and ToDate is **10-01-2021**
The day of a month is not the same here.

Input :

```
FromDate    ToDate
15-01-2018  15-12-2018
15-12-2018  10-10-2020
...
15-10-2020  15-11-2020
15-11-2020  15-12-2020
15-12-2020  10-01-2021
```

output :

```
FromDate    ToDate
15-01-2018  15-02-2018
15-02-2018  15-03-2018
15-03-2018  15-04-2018
...
15-11-2018  15-12-2018
15-12-2018  15-01-2020
15-01-2020  15-02-2020
15-02-2020  15-03-2020
...
15-09-2020  10-10-2020
15-10-2020  15-11-2020
15-11-2020  15-12-2020
15-12-2020  10-01-2021
```

Comment: are you saying you want from/to pairs to be exanded to a sequence of from/to pairs where difference is > 1 month?

Comment: yes @RobRaymond, I would like to expand those dates to a sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *FromDate* generate a list from `date_range()`
- expand it `explode()`
- calc *ToDate*

```
import datetime as dt
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""FromDate    ToDate
15-01-2018  15-12-2018
15-12-2018  15-10-2020
15-10-2020  15-11-2020
15-11-2020  15-12-2020
15-12-2020  10-01-2021"""), sep="\s+")

df.FromDate = pd.to_datetime(df.FromDate)
df.ToDate = pd.to_datetime(df.ToDate)

(df.assign(FromDate=df.apply(lambda r: pd.date_range(dt.date(r.FromDate.year, r.FromDate.month, 1), 
                                                    dt.date(r.ToDate.year, r.ToDate.month, 1) - pd.Timedelta(days=1), 
                                                    freq="MS") + pd.Timedelta(days=r.FromDate.day-1), axis=1))
 .explode("FromDate")
 .assign(
     ToDate=lambda dfa: np.where((dfa.ToDate-dfa.FromDate).gt(dt.timedelta(days=35)),
                                                              dfa.FromDate + pd.DateOffset(months=1),
                                                             dfa.ToDate))
)
```

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""FromDate    ToDate
15-01-2018  15-12-2018
15-12-2018  15-10-2020
15-10-2020  15-11-2020
15-11-2020  15-12-2020
15-12-2020  10-01-2021"""), sep="\s+")
if i give this as my input df it is ending at 2020-11-15 as end date, i would want to see 
15-11-2020  10-12-2020 this as last row

Comment: I just pasted your sample data - you can use whatever is required it will functionality is expand ranges that are more than a month ...

Comment: oops didn't spot last data item ended on 10th of month,  will amend

Comment: updated to consider where *ToDate* is less than a month away from *FromDate*